# identifying whats causing these errors in notepad++

Tags: java

```
import java.util.scanner;
 import java.io.PrintStream;

 public class MoneyConverterProject{

    /**
     * Converts monetary amounts into fewest number of bills and coins starting with $10.
     */
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input = new scanner (System.in);

        //Displays text for user inputs
            System.out.print("Enter monetary amount:");

        //Reserves Memory locations for monetary amounts 
        //convertts amounts into pennies 
        //Calculates remainder for the given inputs
            double originalAmount = input.nextDouble();
            int amountInPennies = (int)(originalAmount * 100.0D);

            int tenDollar = amountInPennies / 1000;
            amountInPennies %=1000;

            int fiveDollar = amountInPennies / 500;
            amountInPennies %=500;

            int oneDollar = amountInPennies / 100;
            amountInPennies %= 100;

            int quarter = amountInPennies / 25;
            amountInPennies %= 25;

            int dime = amountInPennies / 10;
            amountInPennies %= 10;

            int nickel = amountInPennies / 5;
            amountInPennies %= 5;

            int penny = amountInPennies;
            input.close();

        //translate input
        //Displays conversions
            System.out.println("Is equal to:")
            System.out.println(tenDollar + "ten dollar bills")
            System.out.println(fiveDollar + "five dollar bills")
            System.out.println(oneDollar + "one dollar bills")
            System.out.println(quarter + "quarters")
            System.out.println(dime + "dimes")
            System.out.println(nickel + "nickels")
            System.out.println(penny + "pennies")
        }
    }
```

```
Errors:
Process started >>>
MoneyConverterProject.java:50: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println("Is equal to:")
                                              ^
MoneyConverterProject.java:51: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println(tenDollar + "ten dollar bills")
                                                              ^
MoneyConverterProject.java:52: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println(fiveDollar + "five dollar bills")
                                                                ^
MoneyConverterProject.java:53: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println(oneDollar + "one dollar bills")
                                                              ^
MoneyConverterProject.java:54: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println(quarter + "quarters")
                                                    ^
MoneyConverterProject.java:55: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println(dime + "dimes")
                                              ^
MoneyConverterProject.java:56: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println(nickel + "nickels")
                                                  ^
MoneyConverterProject.java:57: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println(penny + "pennies")
```

Explanation: I think the errors are coming from improperly imported imports therefore causing the runtime to not properly scan the text.
     I'm new to writing java and honestly I have little to no clue of what I'm doing. I need some help solving these errors and I don't know where else to turn.

Comment: You're missing a bunch of end semicolons, and the error messages are telling **exactly** where they're missing. Note that the question has nothing to do with Notepad++ and all to do with a basic Java bug. So add the semicolons, and take a look at most any beginning Java tutorial to get a handle on basic Java syntax as it is core information that will be needed in all your future Java endeavors. In the future, please try to write a better question heading, one that's actually informative and describes your actual problem -- yours does not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that obvious mistake. now I feel even more embarrassed but any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, and don't feel bad. The learning curve when learning your first programming language can be steep, and none of us were born with Java programming knowledge. It will come.

Answer (score 0):

No, the error is exactly what it says it is.

```
MoneyConverterProject.java:50: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println("Is equal to:")
```

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the second line.  That's what `error ';' expected` means.  It expected to find a semicolon `;` and the semicolon wasn't there.

Ditto with every other error message, I think.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys you all just saved my noob bacon.

Comment: I fixed Both scanner errors and added semicolons to the output text and everything is great now. Thanks for the help for such a minor thing. I'll be sure to do more troubleshooting next time before running to you guys next time. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should change 'scanner' to 'Scanner' in the import statement, and add ';' to fix compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

you have many error first it is import java.util.Scanner; big S not small also add ; after every system.out.print and Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); scound S is big not small here is your code after fixing error

```
  package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.PrintStream;

 public class test{

    /**
     * Converts monetary amounts into fewest number of bills and coins starting with $10.
     */
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Displays text for user inputs
            System.out.print("Enter monetary amount:");

        //Reserves Memory locations for monetary amounts 
        //convertts amounts into pennies 
        //Calculates remainder for the given inputs
            double originalAmount = input.nextDouble();
            int amountInPennies = (int)(originalAmount * 100.0D);

            int tenDollar = amountInPennies / 1000;
            amountInPennies %=1000;

            int fiveDollar = amountInPennies / 500;
            amountInPennies %=500;

            int oneDollar = amountInPennies / 100;
            amountInPennies %= 100;

            int quarter = amountInPennies / 25;
            amountInPennies %= 25;

            int dime = amountInPennies / 10;
            amountInPennies %= 10;

            int nickel = amountInPennies / 5;
            amountInPennies %= 5;

            int penny = amountInPennies;
            input.close();

        //translate input
        //Displays conversions
            System.out.println("Is equal to:");
            System.out.println(tenDollar + "ten dollar bills");
            System.out.println(fiveDollar + "five dollar bills");
            System.out.println(oneDollar + "one dollar bills");
            System.out.println(quarter + "quarters");
            System.out.println(dime + "dimes");
            System.out.println(nickel + "nickels");
            System.out.println(penny + "pennies");
        }
    }
```